# How to send slider information over websocket in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket, slider

I am developing an application for my Hololens. My environment contains sliders. I am using [websocket-sharp](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38367). I want to send the slider position values (0,180) over the WebSocket. Could someone help me with any pointers regarding how to achieve the same?

Ok as suggested, here are my game object or the sliders I have.

```
 public void initializeSliders(Slider[] sliderList_)
    {
        var CanvasChildren = CanvasObj.GetComponentsInChildren<Slider>();

        for (int i = 0; i < CanvasChildren.Length; i++)
        {
            if (CanvasChildren[i].name == "Slider0")
            {
                sliderList_[0] = CanvasChildren[i];

                sliderList_[0].minValue = lowerLimit[0];
                sliderList_[0].maxValue = upperLimit[0];
                sliderList_[0].value = 0;
            }
            else if (CanvasChildren[i].name == "Slider1")
            {
                sliderList_[1] = CanvasChildren[i];

                sliderList_[1].minValue = lowerLimit[1];
                sliderList_[1].maxValue = upperLimit[1];
                sliderList_[1].value = 0;
            }
            else if (CanvasChildren[i].name == "Slider2")
            {
                sliderList_[2] = CanvasChildren[i];

                sliderList_[2].minValue = lowerLimit[2];
                sliderList_[2].maxValue = upperLimit[2];
                sliderList_[2].value = 0;
            }
         }
    }
```

I would like to get the value of the sliders when the user manipulates them in the hololens and send it over the WebSocket. ( I am new to Unity and C#)

Comment: 1.Get value from slider. 2.Send through socket....Please edit your question with your code and mention where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I am new to Unity and C#, I have just started writing my socket script. Thanks for the quick answer, I will google to find out how to do step 1 and step 2. If I have an error in my code, I will edit and put it here. @Programmer

Comment: Note that Websocket is not the-same as raw socket. The Websocket plugin you linked should have an example script that shows how to use it in the Example folder.